Why does transformer current change with different inductance?
See the LT spice simulation screenshots below. The circuits in both simulations are exactly the same, except for the inductor values used in the transformer. The voltage source is generating a 1 MHz sine output with 10V amplitude. In the first simulation with the 10uH inductors, I get the result I expect. Because the turns ratio in the transformer is 1:1, the resistance R1 to be "transformed" into the same resistance on the other side of the transformer, so V1 sees two 1ohm resistors in series. Current through both R1 and R2 is the same.
However, when I change the inductance of both sides of the transformer to 1nH, there is no longer any voltage across L1. Basically the entire 10V supply voltage can be seen across R2. The voltage across L1 and L2 is still the same, but its closer to 60mV, not the 5V it was in the first circuit.
Why does the transformer behavior change depending on the inductance of the coils even when the turns ratio stays the same in both simulations? There must be some point between 10uH and 1nH where this transition occurs, how could this be calculated? Could someone share an equation that might have predicted this result?



What is the impedance of a 10uH inductor at 1 MHz? What is the impedance of a 1nH inductor at 1 MHz?

You have a voltage divider. At 1 MHz, the inductive reactance of 10 µH is around 63Ω, which is much larger than the value of the R2 resistor. The inductive reactance (XL) for 1 nH will be ten thousand times smaller than 63Ω (6.3mΩ). Also, do not forget that an ideal transformer will have an inductance equal to infinity.
